# One field should not be blank if some fields are blank in Symfony Form

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony 2 (2.4.2) application, there is a Form Type which consists of 3 fields.

I'd like the validation be like this: If `field A` and `field B` are blank, `field C` should not be blank. This means that at least one field should receive some data.

Currently, I check the received data in the controller. Is there a more recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are even easier solutions than writing a custom validator. The easiest of all is probably the expression constraint:

```
class MyEntity
{
    private $fieldA;

    private $fieldB;

    /**
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     expression="this.fieldA != '' || this.fieldB != '' || value != ''",
     *     message="Either field A or field B or field C must be set"
     * )
     */
    private $fieldC;
}
```

You can also add a validation method to your class and annotate it with the Callback constraint:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validateFields(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if ('' === $this->fieldA && '' === $this->fieldB && '' === $this->fieldC) {
        $context->addViolation('At least one of the fields must be filled');
    }
}
```

The method will be executed during the validation of the class.

Comment: I think this answer is better and simpler.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a use case for a [Custom Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html). I haven't used it myself but basically you create a `Constraint` and a `Validator`. You then specify your `Constraint` in your `config/validation.yml`.

```
Your\Bundle\Entity\YourEntity:
    constraints:
        - Your\BundleValidator\Constraints\YourConstraint: ~
```

The actual validation is done by your `Validator`. You can tell Symfony to pass the whole entity to your `validate` method to access multiple fields with:

```
public function getTargets()
{
    return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
}
```

And your `validate`:

```
public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint)
{
    // Do whatever validation you need
    // You can specify an error message inside your Constraint
    if (/* $entity->getFieldA(), ->getFieldB(), ->getFieldC() ... */) {
        $this->context->addViolationAt(
            'foo',
            $constraint->message,
            array(),
            null
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Group Sequence Providers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence-providers), for example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\GroupSequenceProviderInterface;

/**
 * @Assert\GroupSequenceProvider
 */
class MyObject implements GroupSequenceProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"OptionA"})
     */
    private $fieldA;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"OptionA"})
     */
    private $fieldB;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"OptionB"})
     */
    private $fieldC;

    public function getGroupSequence()
    {
        $groups = array('MyObject');

        if ($this->fieldA == null && $this->fieldB == null) {
            $groups[] = 'OptionB';
        } else {
            $groups[] = 'OptionA';
        }

        return $groups;
    }
}
```

Not tested it but I think it would work

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's old question but you can also use the NotBlankIf validator from this bundle https://github.com/secit-pl/validation-bundle

```php
<?php

use SecIT\ValidationBundle\Validator\Constraints as SecITAssert;

class Entity
{
    private ?string $fieldA = null;
    private ?string $fieldB = null;

    #[SecITAssert\NotBlankIf("!this.getFieldA() and !this.getFieldB()")]
    private ?string $fieldC = null;

    public function getFieldA(): string
    {
        return $this->fieldA;
    }

    public function getFieldB(): string
    {
        return $this->fieldB;
    }
}
```